# Newtonsoft.Json: AllowNull bug?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Im trying to write serializer which will serialize/deserialize to **exact same** class structure. So, even if default value of property is not provided - it should throw error. I thought what I accomplished it by setting member handling and contract resolver, but It wont work. Exceptions are not thrown where it should by all means (I explicitly specified it in contract resolver).

And here is my serializer:

```
public sealed class JsonSerializer : ISerializer
{
    private readonly JsonSerializerSettings _settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new RequireObjectPropertiesContractResolver(),//Everything required. Null are allowed.
        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error, //If something missing in target class - it should throw error.
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    };

    public object Deserialize(string input, Type type)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input, type, _settings);
    }

    public string Serialize(object input)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input, _settings);
    }

    private class RequireObjectPropertiesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
        {
            var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
            contract.ItemRequired = Required.AllowNull;
            return contract;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is test case which I can't get working:

```
   [DataContract]
    private class TestInput
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Value0 { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Value1 { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Inner Inner { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    private class Inner
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string NewValue0 { get; set; }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSerialization()
    {
        using (var kernel = new StandardKernel(new MyModule()))
        {
            var serializer = kernel.Get<ISerializer>();

            //It should throw error because Inner not provided as null (not thrown)
            string json = "{\"Value0\":\"test0\", \"Value1\":\"test1\"}";
            Extensions.Throws<Exception> (()=>serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(TestInput)));

            //It should throw error because nothing were provided as null (not thrown)
            json = "{}";
            Extensions.Throws<Exception>(() => serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(TestInput)));

            //this one is correct one (no problems here)
            json = "{\"Value0\":\"test0\", \"Value1\":\"test1\", \"Inner\":null}";
            Extensions.NotThrows(()=>serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(TestInput)));
        }
    }
```

These two tests just won't pass.

Comment: With the latest version of Newtonsoft's JSON serializer, I get: "Additional information: Required property 'Inner' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 36."

Comment: Im using Newtonsoft's JSON  9.0.1. Completely cleaned my project and rebuilded. Still, no success.

Comment: Framework version? I'm using a console application compiled against 4.5.1 in my test.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: OK, I still get an error raised when compiled for 4.6.1. Clutching at straws here: have you confirmed that Ninject is returning the correct serializer?

Comment: Yeap, it is single implementation at the moment.

Comment: @eocron you didn't specify that the members are *required*. You should use  `[DataMember(IsRequired =true)]`. The default is `false`. Your code would have worked if you hadn't set the `DataContract`, `DataMember` atrributes which take precedence over the default settings

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I did. *RequireObjectPropertiesContractResolver* created especially for that purpose. As you see, I'm setting *AllowNull* which by description force this requirement with allowing null if it typed explicitly. Hmm, I will see what about DataContract is wrong, but I think this is a bug.

Comment: eocron - Sorry, I didn't test properly. I'm seeing the same thing as you now, and it's "resolved" by what Panagiotis said. Beyond that, I'm not sure how to resolve your problem. Apologies.

Comment: @eocron it's not a bug. The *more* specific setting takes precedence over the generic setting. The default value of the `IsRequired` parameter of `DataMember()` is false. The attribute you set *explicitly* defines an optional attribute. Remove all attributes and your settings will work as expected

Comment: @eocron the class you created doesn't say that everything is required. It says that, for required items, nulls are allowed. Even if you had set that to `Always` though, the `DataMember` takes precedence

Comment: Oh, now I understand why it is happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some time I managed to make it work. DataContract applied to my classes were in the way so I just reassigned values they are setting:

```
    private class RequireObjectPropertiesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
        {
            var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
            contract.ItemRequired = Required.AllowNull;
            return contract;
        }

        protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            var properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
            foreach (var p in properties)
            {
                p.Required = Required.AllowNull;
            }
            return properties;
        }
    }
```

Just setted Required.AllowNull on all properties, instead of contract itself.